# "Create a Playlist" with Spotify Web API returning 201 but without a playlist object

Tags: javascript, http, async-await, spotify, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a web app using the Spotify Web API, part of which includes creating a playlist and then filling it with some tracks.

According to the [API reference](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/), the response to the request should return a playlist object containing details on the playlist and, more importantly for me, the API endpoint for the new playlist so that I can immediately use it to add tracks.

The response I'm getting is 201, and I can see the new playlist created in Spotify, but the response contains no body and nowhere is the endpoint to interact with the created playlist.

Is my request somehow malformed or am I missing something in the response?

```
// Test create playlist
  const createPlaylist = async (accessToken, userID, tracks) => {
    // Create empty playlist and retrieve endpoint
    const emptyPlaylist = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userID}/playlists`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'name': 'Intersection Test',
        'public': false,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      }
    })
    .then(async response => {
      // Add tracks to playlist
      if (tracks.length > 100) error("Playlist too large for one call");
      const fillPlaylist = await fetch(response.url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        body: {
          'uris': tracks
        }
      });
    });
```

[Image of response in Chrome console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCPPC.png)

Comment: The documentation indicates the that there is a header on the response indicating the url of the new playlist. Can you check headers for that url on the response?

Comment: have the a header location field? then the answer is to find there

Comment: Yeah that's where I expected that to be too, but the headers are completely empty.

Comment: Your image of the response, where is that coming from exactly? It looks to have a url header entry.

Comment: That url is just the same as the one that the request was sent to, gives nothing identifying about the playlist.

The url I'm looking for should be in the form 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists//{playlist_id}/tracks'

Comment: What’s the exact error message the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: There's no error, except when I try to make the second POST request since I can't obtain the correct url to post to from the first request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, my problem was that I forgot to apply `response.json()` before using the body, so I was printing the Response stream rather than the actual resolution of the Promise.